# mono_method_get_unmanaged_thunk - crash with /O2 compiler setting

Tags: mono, crash

I've been integrating mono runtime with certain app lately, and I was doing most of the tests using `Debug` configuration. Recently, I switched to `Release`, and I noticed it started to crash. (I'm using msvs2010 compiler).

I tracked it down, and found out it's occuring when calling function pointers obtained via `mono_method_get_unmanaged_thunk`. The one difference between configurations that was causing it was optimizations `/O2` in release vs `/Od` in debug. From what I managed to observe, the crash occurs right after the managed method leaves. Are there some known considerations about those optimizations?

My scenario is following:

In native code I'm obtaining function pointer to jump into managed land:

```
bool (*Some_Method) (MonoObject*, int, MonoObject*, MonoObject*, MonoObject*, MonoException**);
```

On managed side, the method is non-static method, so the first argument is `this`:

```
bool Managed_Method(int, SomeType a2, SomeType a3, SomeType a4)
```

While initializing native side, I'm fetching pointer like that:

```
Some_Method = (bool(*)(MonoObject*, int, MonoObject*, MonoObject*, MonoObject*, MonoException**)) mono_method_get_unmanaged_thunk(method)
```

And I'm calling managed method using obtained pointer:

```
bool result = Some_Method(v, o1, o2, o3)
```

where o1, o2, o3 are either nulls, or valid managed objects.

The body of the method does nothing really, in current scenario it just leaves with false, after doing one boolean check.

Mono runtime: `2.10.8`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got my answer - the function pointers returned by `mono_method_get_unmanaged_thunk` are `__stdcall` convention, whereas my compiler's default is `cdecl`, hence I changed:

```
bool (*Some_Method) (MonoObject*, int, MonoObject*, MonoObject*, MonoObject*, MonoException**)
```

into

```
bool (__stdcall*Some_Method) (MonoObject*, int, MonoObject*, MonoObject*, MonoObject*, MonoException**)
```

and now the call is performed without crash.

Seems like `Debug` settings were adjusting the stack pointer or some registers (dunno what exactly, I'm not very knowledgeable on that matter), and that's why it was running without problems, as the `stdcall` and `cdecl` are very different and such mismatch could result in crash in both configurations.